# Azure data factory - web activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to use the Web Activity using the GET HTTP request to retrieve data from an endpoint. I need to filter and format dates but the body does not come up for the GET. (only for the POST, PUT) etc.

How do I add 'body'data in the GET?
Please help

Comment: It’s not really clear what you mean.  Please provide some screenshots of the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

**Body** property in [web activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#type-properties) represents the payload that is sent to the endpoint and is enabled/required only for **POST/PUT** request methods.

If you want to filter/format response you can pass the output of web activity to filter activity or set variable activity.

Example:

[image]

Set Variable activity:

`@string(activity('Web1').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders)`

[image]